# Need to have a grid Grouped into logical groups based on date

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, devexpress

I'm dealing with a situation where I need to group my DevExpress grid on the basis of a date column. The issue is, I need my groups to be called: Past, Current, and Future. Here is the LINQ:

```
GridJobSummary.DataSource = from luke in DbContext.JobBookings
            where luke.LocumID == LocumID
            orderby luke.Job.JobDate descending
            select new {
                luke.JobID,
                luke.Job.JobDate,
                ClientID = luke.Job.Branch.ClientID,
                ClientName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", luke.Job.Branch.Client.Name, luke.Job.Branch.Client.Number),
                BranchID = luke.Job.BranchID,
                BranchName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", luke.Job.Branch.Number, luke.Job.Branch.Number),
                JobBookingStatusName = luke.JobBookingStatus.Name
            };

GridJobSummaryView.Columns["JobID"].Visible = false;
GridJobSummaryView.Columns["ClientID"].Visible = false;
GridJobSummaryView.Columns["BranchID"].Visible = false;

GridJobSummaryView.Columns["JobDate"].DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
GridJobSummaryView.Columns["JobDate"].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy";
GridJobSummaryView.Columns["JobDate"].SortOrder = ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
```

Now,

If [job date < Today], it goes into *Past* group.

If [job date >= Today **and** <= (Today + 1 Month)], it's *Current*.

If [job date > (Today + 1 Month)], it's *Future*.

How can I have my grid grouped into this virtual group? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property "GroupName" to the selected objects:

```
select new {
                luke.JobID,
                luke.Job.JobDate,
                ClientID = luke.Job.Branch.ClientID,
                ClientName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", luke.Job.Branch.Client.Name, luke.Job.Branch.Client.Number),
                BranchID = luke.Job.BranchID,
                BranchName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", luke.Job.Branch.Number, luke.Job.Branch.Number),
                JobBookingStatusName = luke.JobBookingStatus.Name,
                GroupName = GetGroupNameByDate(luke.Job.JobDate)
            };

// .....
string GetGroupNameByDate(DateTime date) {
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    if ( date < today ) { return "Past"; }
    else if ( date >= today && date <= today.AddMonths( 1 ) ) { return "Current"; }
    else { return "Future"; }
}
```